# Pandas: issue with unique groupby and datetime

Tags: datetime, pandas

I have a CSV file like this:

```
id,timestamp
1,2015-03-02
2,2015-03-03
```

which I then load into a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=['id'], parse_dates=['timestamp'])
```

then I group by id, select the timestamp column, and apply a function to return timestamp - day

```
df.groupby(level='id')['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.Timedelta('1 days'))
```

result:

```
id
1   2015-03-01
2   2015-03-02
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However, when I apply unique() to the groupby object, the timestamps change into an unexpected format.

```
df.groupby(level='id')['timestamp'].unique().apply(lambda x: x - pd.Timedelta('1 days'))

id
1    [2015-03-02T00:00:00.000000000]
2    [2015-03-03T00:00:00.000000000]
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

How do I maintain the format of the dates?

Comment: The issue is that `unique` will return an array containing all of the unique values.  What are you trying to achieve?  This seems like an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @root tl;dr I'm essentially trying to join two DataFrames together, df1 and df2. df1 has a timestamp column and df2 has a timestamp. However, in df1 each index has multiple instances, whereas in df2 each index only has one instance. Therefore, after joining, I am left with a DataFrame where each index has repeating values of the timestamp column in df2. This is why I am taking unique() because I only want unique timestamps. I'm grouping on id because I want all timestamps for each id. Then for each timestamp I am applying this function. But I'm confused why the datetime format is changing.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible data set (with duplicates) and desired data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unique` returns a *sequence* of unique values. That is why the result of

```
df.groupby(level='id')['timestamp'].unique()
```

is a Series of lists.

Instead, to remove the duplicates, use `drop_duplicates`:

```
result = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'timestamp']).set_index('id')
```

Since `drop_duplicates` requires subset to be a list of columns, `reset_index` was used above to move the `id` index level to a column, and `set_index` was used to move it back to the index after dropping duplicates.

---

Avoid using `apply` when possible. When passed a custom Python function, `apply` calls the function in a plain Python loop -- thus it is slower than vectorized operations.
If you can perform the calculation with vectorized operations, your code will run faster.

In this case, it is likely to be faster to subtract 1 day from the entire column all at once (regardless of group or duplicates):

```
df['timestamp'] -= pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

One case where this might be slower is if the DataFrame is huge but composed of
only one (or a few) `('id', 'timestamp')` group(s). But in general, applying a
vectorized operation to an entire column will be faster than multiple function
calls applied to smaller groups.

---

So, for example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [Timestamp('2015-03-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-03-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-03-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-03-03 00:00:00')]}, index=pd.Index([1, 1, 1, 2], name='id'),)
#     timestamp
# id           
# 1  2015-03-02
# 1  2015-03-02
# 1  2015-03-03
# 2  2015-03-03

df['timestamp'] -= pd.Timedelta(days=1)
result = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'timestamp']).set_index('id')

print(result)
#     timestamp
# id           
# 1  2015-03-01
# 1  2015-03-02
# 2  2015-03-02
```

Answer (score 0):

groupby returns arrays, which is why you see them displayed like that. If you want a series that has the timestamps, you need to grab those values out with something like the apply method below.

```
grouped = df.groupby(level='id')['timestamp'].unique().apply(lambda x: x - pd.Timedelta('1 days'))

grouped.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

>

```
id
1   2015-03-01
2   2015-03-02
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The format is changing to a list because you are asking for the unique values (of which there may be multiple). You could, say, return only the first:

`df.groupby(level='id')['timestamp'].unique().apply(lambda x: x[0] - pd.Timedelta('1 days'))`

PS. My guess is that @unutbu's solution will be better for you.